# java doesn't run if structure inside of onclick listener

Tags: java, android

All you must see as code is below.

```
bSet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String first = etFirstNumber.getText().toString();
                String second = etSecondNumber.getText().toString();
                int f = Integer.parseInt(first);
                int s = Integer.parseInt(second);

                int calc = 0;
                int n = 0;

                if(s < f)
                {
                    calc = f - s;
                    n = s;
                }else if(f > s){
                    calc =  s - f;
                    n = f;
                }

                int number = n + (int) (Math.random() * calc);

                String result = String.valueOf(number);

                tvDescription.setText(result);
            }
        });
```

You can think `first` as 35 and `second` as 17. I get 0 as result everytime? What is the problem? Can't I use if clauses inside of onclicklistener?

Comment: Are you sure that the method is completing and isn't throwing an exception you're not seeing?

Comment: Well if s == f then yeah n will equal 0 all the time

Comment: @codeMagic result = 0. chrylis no

Comment: Have you done **any** debugging to see why? This is very important if you are going to be a developer. Set a breakpoint and see what the values are at different points in your code compared to what they should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

both your conditions are the same:

```
if(s < f) {
    calc = f - s;
    n = s;
}else if(f > s){
    calc =  s - f;
    n = f;
 }
```

so

```
if(s < f)
```

and

```
}else if(f > s){
```

are the same

change to

```
}else if(f < s){
```